# how to change the yapsy plugin default file format?

Tags: python

I want to change the default file format extension of the yapsy plugin that looks like ***name.yapsy-plugin*** to ***simply name.info***

I have even found the documentation here http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/PluginFileLocator.html But I am confused how to really implement it.

For now I am just working with the default file format and working well. I just want to make a change in extension. Can anyone make me understand the documentation and thus in the future I can tackle such problems.

```
try:
        simplePluginManager = PluginManager()
        simplePluginManager.setPluginPlaces(["plugins/"])
        simplePluginManager.collectPlugins()
        pluginlist = {}

        for plugininfo in simplePluginManager.getAllPlugins():
            print "Running the plugin--", plugininfo.name
            # running the plugins
            pluginlist[plugininfo.name] = plugininfo.plugin_object.run(
                cons.PLUGIN_CONFIG_PATH, outputpath, finallogs, plugininfo.name)
    except Exception as error:
        print "Plugin Configuration Error", error
        traceback.print_exc(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
simplePluginManager = PluginManager()
```

to

```
simplePluginManager = PluginManager(plugin_info_ext="info")
```

Comment: I have done it using the ConfigurablePluginManager instead 
`manager = ConfigurablePluginManager()
 manager.setPluginInfoExtension("info")`